# Java List should always have particular value as first item

Tags: java, collections

I have a pojo like below,

```
class Employee 
{
    private String employeeName;
    private String age;
    //getter();setter();
    ....
}
```

and I have `employeeList` which has below value,

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Values: `[{"ccc", 20}, {"bbb", 30}, {"aaa", 40}]`

I want `employeeList` with above value, but that list should have "bbb" obj always first. How to implement this. We can't simply use sorting on employee name.

Comment: Why can you not just use sorting on employee name with a custom comparator (Or have Employee implement comparable so that bbb is first in the natural order)? Seems like the obvious solution.

Comment: which order i have to use, ASC or DESC. If i use ASC "aaa" will come first or if i use DESC "ccc" always comes first. But I want with some specific value like "bbb".

Comment: Like i wrote you have to use a **custom comparator** that you write yourself or implement comparable in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `Collections.sort` and provide a `Comparator` e.g.

```
public void sortList(String byString){
  Collections.sort(employeeList, new Comparator<Employee>() {
          @Override
          public int compare(Employee lhs, Employee rhs) {
              if (lhs.getEmployeeName().equals(byString)) return -1;
              if (rhs.getEmployeeName().equals(byString)) return 0;
              return 1;
           }
   });
 }
```

Ideone: https://ideone.com/FCRxwp

Comment: But i need to pass the value(eg "bbb") at runtime

Comment: @Srinivasan this still works, just replace `"bbb"` with you variable you pass in instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: Code is missing a parenthesis in the if statements. Also: If both lhs and rhs employeeNames are "bbb" it should return 0 and not 1. This might cause an exception to be thrown as it violates the comparable contract. And last but not least it actually sorts "bbb" as last elements and not first.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS fixed

Comment: @Srinivasan See my edit. You can change it to accept a parameter

Comment: Please don't encourage newbies to omit braces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it variable and be able to pass what should be sorted at the beginning you can just create a simple method:

```
public static void sort(List<Employee> list, String nameToSortAtBeginning) {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Employee>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
            if(nameToSortAtBeginning.equals(o1.getEmployeeName()) && !nameToSortAtBeginning.equals(o2.getEmployeeName())) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return o1.getEmployeeName().compareTo(o2.getEmployeeName());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and then call that method:

```
sort(employeeList, "bbb");
```

**Note:** The above code will not work if you have *null* as possible values for some employee names. If having null as a value there is a possibility you have to add null handling in the comparator as well.